# Jsoup, http error 416, parsing HTML

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I do not know much about jsoup or HTML parsing. I am trying to pull information from whitepages.com

```
try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.whitepages.com/phone/1-###-###-####").get();
         numberinfo = doc.select(".phone-list-data");
     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting `org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL.` with status 416.

I've done some research and it shows something about ranges, does it have to do with the input at the end for the specific phone number?

Is there a way to have jsoup parse info like this?

Comment: can you give an example url?

Comment: You can change the ###-###-#### to any phone number,

480-307-7421 

That should more than likely return a tmobile phone number in arizona.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so `Http 416` error occurs when you ask for more data than available, such request is syntactically valid but not satisfiable. For example if you are to request a file of `1K bytes` and the actual file on server is less than the requested size, server will issue 416 error, If you request for less bytes than the actual size of server content than you will receive response with http status 206 (Partial Content).

Why is it occurring in your case?
Probably and this is my guess not sure, `Jsoup` is adding range header to your request, see `Jsoup.connect(url).maxBodySize()` in Jsoup which sets max bytes to read and defaults to 1MB. In your case even if you change this to `200 bytes` same error will occur.

**Solution :** After your `Jsoup.connect(url)` method add `ignoreHttpErrors(true)` to ignore such errors, e.g:

```
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.whitepages.com/phone/1-###-###-####").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
            Elements elements = doc.select(".phone-list-data");
            System.out.println(doc.html());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I think I am getting some kind of access denied return. I am getting the HTML page information but I am unable to see anything specific like if i were to view the source directly on the page. I know it can be done because the in browser "Try jsoup online" works perfectly for it.